# Transfer driver in Raspberry Pi 2 Model B with Screen Kedai 3.5

Tags: pi-2, screen, touchscreen

I have a Raspberry Pi 2 Model B and I bought an 3.5" LCD screen from China called Kedai 3.5. To be able to use it, the Chinese company provides a link for downloading a Raspbian image with the screen driver installed. After loading this image to the SD card, the Raspberry Pi boots up perfectly.

But:
As I don't trust their image to be free of any spyware or virus, I would like to transfer the necessary drivers from that working Raspbian system and download and install Ubuntu 16.04 from [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/RaspberryPi).

I already tried to copy the `*.img` files from `/boot/` and as well to copy all the files in `/lib/` from the working Raspbian to the desired Ubuntu. Unfortunately, without success. After having done so and trying to boot the system on the Raspberry, the screen remains white.

What files and folders do I have to transfer to make that work?

Comment: why not just google tutorials on using similar displays? such as tft if your display is tft based?

Comment: @MohammadAli Tried that already without success. Kedai 3.5 seems to be seldomly used (in my experience, I may be wrong). Hence, all the tutorials I found managed screens of different brands than Kedai 3.5 and are therefore useless. This is why I posted here.

Comment: do you have any idea what protocol is being utilized by the display?

Comment: @MohammadAli Yep, that would be SPI.

Comment: Just google tft display tutorials and you should be alright. Have you tried using the os that they supplied you with at all? Because it would be helpful to know that you hooked up the display right and that the display is in working order

Comment: @MohammadAli Yep, image works perfectly. I have a working copy of Raspbian downloaded from the website of Kedei, the Chinese company.

Comment: Have you tried to contact them, and ask about how they are interfacing with their display?

Comment: @MohammadAli Yep, already done. Unfortunately, useless. They only provide a 4GB Rasbian (rpi_35_v3_jessie8_kernel_4_1_12.img) for Kedei 3.5, but not only the driver itself. This is why I want to extract it manually and then run it in Ubuntu.

Comment: That a unlikely to happen as they are probably using some proprietary software to trick the gpu into hardware acceleration, you have a better chance trying to reverse engineering the device,

Comment: @MohammadAli Ok, how would I reverse engineer it then?

Comment: Start by looking at the hardware on the thing and Google it too see which display protocols are being utilized then google drivers and install them

Comment: @MohammadAli I'll give that a try.

Answer (score -1):

I re-organized the README.txt extracted from LCD_show.tar.tz that I extracted from the rpi_35_v1_B_B+_PI2 to make this a little easier to follow, plus added a couple missing steps. I am sure there are other ways to accomplish this, but this worked for me.

Two methods for installation:

- You can burn the image file "rpi_35_B_B+_PI2.img" to SD card ([ApplePi-Baker](http://www.tweaking4all.com/software/macosx-software/macosx-apple-pi-baker/) is free and easy)

-or-

- Install files using terminal

Here is the terminal command to transfer the .tar.gz from PC to Raspberry Pi
(the closer to the `/home/` path the easier):

```
scp /path/to/local/file pi@your.rpi.ip.address:/path/to/remote/file
```

- SSH into the raspberry Pi: `ssh pi@your.rpi.ip.address` [Default password is *raspberry*]
- Decompress the file: `tar -xzvf LCD_show.tar.gz`
- Change into the new file/path: `cd ./LCD_show`
- Update from same path: `sudo apt-get update`
- Install new driver: `sudo ./LCD35_v1`

Then after a few seconds, the system will reboot

If you want to use HDMI, you can run command: `sudo./LCD_hdmi`

---

Make sure you are not overclocking the Pi - once the driver installed and the Pi rebooted, my "always" steady white screen was now flickering.

The version numbers from `LCD_show.tar.gz` need to be the same version printed on the back of the screen.

If your file name uses Chinese writing, just rename the file in English but keep the .tar.gz extension.